# get value from variable

Tags: java, apache, velocity

Good Afternoon in my timezone.

I am using Velocity 1.4.
In a template i have the following code :

```
#set($countRow = 0)
....
<td width="80" align="center" class="tgDataColumn"   id="MAIL_LIST_ID_R{$countRow}_C0" nowrap="">$row.sector</td>
<td width="80" align="center"  class="tgDataColumn"   id="MAIL_LIST_ID_R'$countRow'_C6" nowrap="">$row.isin</td>
<td width="150" align="center"  class="tgDataColumn"   id="MAIL_LIST_ID_R$countRow_C7" nowrap="">$row.totalPositions</td>
```

With following results :

```
<td width="75" align="center"   class="tgDataColumn"   id="MAIL_LIST_ID_R{5}_C5" nowrap="">1040403154H</td>
<td width="80" align="center"  class="tgDataColumn"   id="MAIL_LIST_ID_R'5'_C6" nowrap="">QA0007227737</td>
<td width="150" align="center"  class="tgDataColumn"   id="MAIL_LIST_ID_R$countRow_C7" nowrap="">1</td>
```

How do i get the value in **countRow** variable without quotes or brackets to obtain something like this :

```
<td width="75" align="center"   class="tgDataColumn"   id="MAIL_LIST_ID_R5_C5" nowrap="">1040403154H</td>
```

Thanks in advance 
Best regards.

Comment: What is happening now ? It's working fine like that in my current templates

Comment: I am not able to get the value of countRow without printing the brackets or the quotes, if i just use the $countRow , it prints the $countRow directly.

Comment: I already found the answer, i must put the first bracket after the dollar sign and not before , like this id="MAIL_LIST_ID_R${countRow}_C0"